# NextDate Should be Greater than Previous Date Validation Script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put a simple client side validation using javascript - which will validate if NextDate is greater than previous date. I'm calling the method onclick="ValidateEndDate();" on my submit button. But it seems to be not working. I need to understand what mistake I'm making. Thank you very much in advance. :)

```
<%-- 
Document   : ctsCaseDetailRegistration
Created on : Jan 16, 2016, 12:52:37 AM
Author     : nishad
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>User Registration</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prism.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chosen.css">
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        /* fix rtl for demo */
        .chosen-rtl .chosen-drop { left: -9000px; }
    </style>

    <script src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function () {
            alert("submitted!");
        }
        });
        });</script>




    <style>
        div.dataTables_wrapper {
            width: 1100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>

    <style>

        #leftContainer {
            float:left;
        }

        #rightContainer {
            float:none;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <%=session.getAttribute("name")%> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="LogOutController"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="DashBoardController?action=listDairy"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>                  
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Forms</a>
                    </li>                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Home <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="DashBoardController?action=listDairy">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Administration</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="UserController?action=listUser">Users</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>  
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Operations <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo1" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="AdvocateController?action=listAdvocate">Advocates</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="ClientController?action=listClient">Clients</a>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="CourtController?action=listCourt">Courts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="DashBoardController?action=listDairy">Registrar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Case Category</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="CaseStageController?action=listCaseStage">Case Stage</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="DocumentController?action=listDocument">Documents</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Case <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo2" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="CaseMasterController?action=listCaseMaster">Case Updates</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="CaseDetailController?action=listCaseDetail">Case Diary</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="CaseDocumentController?action=listDocument">Case Documents</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Notice Information</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Allocate Cases</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Payments</a>
                            </li>                               
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>


        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Case Registration
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  <a href="index.jsp">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>  Case Registration
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <form role="form" method="POST" class="register" action='CaseDetailController' name="frmAddCaseDetail">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p>
                                    <select data-placeholder="Select Document Type..." name ="cad_FileName1" class="chosen-select" style="width:450px;" >
                                        <c:forEach items="${casemasters}" var="casemaster">                                                
                                            <option value="${casemaster.cad_ID}" ${casedetail.cad_ID == casemaster.cad_ID ? 'selected' : ''}>${casemaster.cad_CaseNo} || ${casemaster.cad_FileName}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>  
                                    <button type="submit" name="GetDetails" value="GetDetails" class="btn btn-primary">Get Details</button>
                                    <button type="submit" name="AddCase" value="AddCase" class="btn btn-primary">Add Case</button>

                                </p>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="panel panel-success" style="width: 1000px;">
                                            <div class="panel-heading" style="width: 1000px;">
                                                <h3 class="panel-title" style="width: 1000px;"><i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Case History</h3>
                                            </div>

                                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>

                                                        <th>Update</th>
                                                        <th>Delete</th>
                                                        <th>CaseID</th>
                                                        <th>CaseDetailID</th>                                                                                                                                           
                                                        <th>Previous Date(s)</th>                                                             
                                                        <th>Stage</th>
                                                        <th>Judge</th>                    
                                                        <th>Rojnama</th>                                                                              
                                                        <th>Court</th>                                           

                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>

                                                <tbody>
                                                    <c:forEach items="${casedetails}" var="casedetail">
                                                        <tr>

                                                            <td><a href="CaseDetailController?action=edit&CaseDetailID=<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_ID}"/>">Edit</a></td>
                                                            <td><a href="CaseDetailController?action=delete&CaseDetailID=<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_ID}"/>">Delete</a></td>
                                                            <td><c:out value="${casedetail.cad_ID}" /></td>
                                                            <td><c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_ID}" /></td>

                                                            <td><fmt:formatDate value="${casedetail.ccd_CurrentDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /></td>                                              
                                                            <td><c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Stage}" /></td>
                                                            <td><c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Judge}" /></td>
                                                            <td><c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Rojnama}" /></td>                                                                
                                                            <td><c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Court}" /></td>                                                                
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </c:forEach>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>                                           
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  class="form-control" placeholder="Case ID" name="cad_id" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.cad_ID}" />" /> 
                                </p> 
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  class="form-control" placeholder="Registration No" name="cad_RegNo" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.cad_RegNo}" />" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p>                                   
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  class="form-control" placeholder="Case Number" name="cad_CaseNo" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.cad_CaseNo}" />" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  class="form-control" placeholder="File Number" name="cad_FileNo" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.cad_FileNo}" />" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text" readonly="readonly"  class="form-control" placeholder="File Name" name="cad_FileName" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.cad_FileName}" />" />                                             
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" placeholder="Previous Date" name="ccd_PreviousDate" value="<fmt:formatDate value="${casedetail.ccd_CurrentDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />" /> 
                                </p>  
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder= "<fmt:formatDate value="${casedetail.ccd_CurrentDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />" name="ccd_CurrentDate" /> 
                                </p>                                    
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Stage" name="ccd_Stage" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Stage}" />"  />                                             
                                </p>    
                                <p>                                        
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Judge" name="ccd_Judge" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Judge}" />" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Rojnama" name="ccd_Rojnama" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Rojnama}" />"  /> 
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Judgment" name="ccd_Judgment" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Judgment}" />" />                                             
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks" name="ccd_Remarks" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Remarks}" />" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Court" name="ccd_Court" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_Court}" />" /> 
                                </p>



                                <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="ccd_DeleteFlag" value="<c:out value="${casedetail.ccd_DeleteFlag}" />" /> 
                                <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="ccd_ActiveFlag" value="<c:out value="true" />" /> 
                                <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="ccd_CreateDate" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="<%= new java.util.Date()%>" />" />                
                                <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="ccd_CreateUser" value="<c:out value="1" />" />                 
                                <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="ccd_ModifyDate" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="<%= new java.util.Date()%>" />" />                
                                <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="ccd_ModifyUser" value="<c:out value="1" />" /> 

                                <p>
                                    <button type="submit" name="SaveDetails" value="SaveDetails" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ValidateEndDate();">Submit</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                               <script>

                                    function ValidateEndDate() {
                                       var StartDate= document.getElementById('ccd_PreviousDate').value;
                                        var EndDate= document.getElementById('ccd_CurrentDate').value;
                                        var eDate = new Date(EndDate);
                                        var sDate = new Date(StartDate);
                                        if(StartDate!= '' && StartDate!= '' && sDate> eDate)
                                        {
                                                alert("Please ensure that the Next Date is greater than Previous Date");
                                                return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                </script>
                        </form>

                    </div>




                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

        <!-- /#wrapper -->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var config = {
            '.chosen-select': {},
            '.chosen-select-deselect': {allow_single_deselect: true},
            '.chosen-select-no-single': {disable_search_threshold: 10},
            '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!'},
            '.chosen-select-width': {width: "95%"}
        }
        for (var selector in config) {
            $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
        }
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: If you provide a working fiddle, it will be more easier to debug you code, and find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and changed little but to run it in my node command prompt, It worked, this is how it looks

```
    function ValidateEndDate() {

            var d = new Date();
            var EndDate= d;
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + 86400000);

          var StartDate= new Date();
          var sDate = new Date(StartDate);
          var eDate = new Date(EndDate);


             console.log("Start Date : "  + StartDate);            
             console.log("End Date : " + d);

              if(StartDate!= '' && EndDate!= '' && sDate> eDate)
                  {
                   console.log("Please ensure that the end Date is greater than Previous Date");
                   return false;
                  }

                  if(StartDate!= '' && EndDate!= '' && sDate < eDate)
                  {
                   console.log("Please ensure that the Start Date is greater than Previous Date");
                   return false;
                  }
     }
  ValidateEndDate();
```

I am not sure why you are not comparing the `EndDate`. I have corrected that too. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This comparison depends on the format in which the date is entered. Assuming a standard format `(YYYY-MM-DD)`, you can do this like:

```js
function ValidateEndDate() {
  var StartDate = document.getElementById('ccd_PreviousDate').value;
  var EndDate = document.getElementById('ccd_CurrentDate').value;
  var eDate = new Date(EndDate);
  var sDate = new Date(StartDate);
  if (StartDate != '' && StartDate != '' && sDate.getTime() > eDate.getTime()) {
    alert("Please ensure that the Next Date is greater than Previous Date");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Fetch the timestamp using `.getTime()` and then compare that.

Comment: Comparing JS dates without using `.getTime()` will work well, so it's not the problem here.

Comment: @MuhammadAref yea i know that, the issue lies in the format of the enetered date.

Comment: He is using `sDate > eDate`, and it's correct and working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = new Date($('#startDate').val());
var endDate = new Date($('#endDate').val());

if (startDate < endDate){
    alert("Please ensure that the Next Date is greater than Previous Date");
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11913877)

Comment: Hi everyone, This function is working now. I was not using id in my text box definition. Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: Hi everyone - I'm just trying to better this validation now. I've included a checkbox on my jsp form which - if checked will not call this validation. Can someone help me with this?